# Getting Error with rest_framework_mongoengine with django

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

After serializing the model in view when i am trying to enter the RESTapi url getting error 
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

using mongoengine so haven't set any database. Worked perfectly before tried api integration

```
settings.py

import mongoengine

DBNAME = 'database'
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
mongoengine.connect(DBNAME,host=MONGO_HOST, port=MONGO_PORT)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_mongoengine',

'api'
```

)

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': '',
    'NAME': '',
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

by mongo docs [setup](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html) did you try it?
by django docs [databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/settings/#databases) `to be used with Django` but you just create `mongoengine.connect` inside your settins, and it does not used by django.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME' : 'my_database'
    }
}
```

and have you look on the [python-eve](http://python-eve.org/index.html) for create mongodb-restapi?

Comment: But i am using mongoengine so i don't need to use django_mongodb_engine engine . Isn't it ??

Comment: ahhhhh may be that's why by admin panel also not working with mongodb.  So i need both mongoengine.connect and 'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',. Or i need to change anything for connecting database

Comment: So no need import mongoengine right ?? Also no need to install any app !!!

Comment: And what if is use  `default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'}`

Comment: need install app, but not need import, for last question try to read all docs i add by links in the answer